# How can install ICONV in windows server 2012

Tags: windows, cmd, server, iconv

I need to install iconv in windwos server 2012 can you help me please for use in line commande

i have try to downloand  iconv.dll, but i dont know how palce in windows for use in cmd  ?

Comment: This question does not belong on this website. You should make a google search, you will probably find a tutorial showing you how to solve your problem. Please take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) before asking a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `regsvr32 "c:\folder\iconv.dll"` or `regsvr32 /I "c:\folder\iconv.dll"` or `c:\windows\syswow64\regsvr32 "c:\folder\iconv.dll"` or `c:\windows\syswow64\regsvr32 /i "c:\folder\iconv.dll"`.